# How can I view branches other than master in gitweb?

Tags: git, gitweb

I'd like to be able to see changes I've made to a file in a branch other than master. Is there a way to do this?

Additionally it would be really nice if I could diff between the heads of multiple branches, eg MyBranch's HEAD and master's HEAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the heads (branches) and tags are listed on the project summary page (`/?p=yourrepo.git;a=summary`). Gitweb doesn't currently support diffing the full tree against another commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify branches with h=refs/heads/XXX . For example, to see branch "develop" of project testing, put the parameters /?p=teseting.git;a=log;h=refs/heads/develop

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the changes introduced to `README.txt` on the latest commit on branch `documentation`:

```
git diff -p -1 documentation -- README.txt
```

(or use `gitk documentation` for a visual tool).

To show the difference between the head of `branchA` and `branchB`:

```
git diff branchA branchB
```

Answer (score 0):

The project summary page, which lists (as stated in [ellotheth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407067/ellotheth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571807/6309)) all branches, slightly changes its branch order management:

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), **tie-break branches** that point at the same object in the list of branches on GitWeb to **show the one pointed at by HEAD early**.

See [commit a45e390](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a45e390ad6ad1f26967a40e7771777f70a77d719) (09 Jun 2021) by [Greg Hurrell (`wincent`)](https://github.com/wincent).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9762646](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9762646ee42b775139b4d519d090808cbdd3bdeb), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`gitweb`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a45e390ad6ad1f26967a40e7771777f70a77d719): use HEAD as secondary sort key in `git_get_heads_list()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Greg Hurrell</sup>

> The "heads" section on the `gitweb` summary page shows heads in `-committerdate` order (ie. the most recently-modified ones at the top), tie-breaking equal-dated refs using the implicit `refname` sort fallback.
>
> This recency-based ordering appears in multiple places in the UI, such as the project listing, the tags list, and even the shortlog and log views.
>
> Given two equal-dated refs, however, sorting the `HEAD` ref before the non-`HEAD` ref provides more useful signal than merely sorting by refname.
> For example, say we had "`master`" and "`trunk`" both pointing at the same commit but "`trunk`" was `HEAD`, sorting "`trunk`" first helps communicate its special status as the default branch that you'll check out if you clone the repo.
>
> Add `-HEAD` as a secondary sort key to the [`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a45e390ad6ad1f26967a40e7771777f70a77d719/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> call in `git_get_heads_list()` to provide the desired behavior.
> The most recently committed refs will appear first, but `HEAD`-ness will be used as a tie-breaker.
> Note that `refname` is the implicit fallback sort key, which means that two same-dated non-`HEAD` refs will continue to be sorted in lexicographical order, as they are today.